# P-класс задач и NP- класс задач

Tags: теория, алгоритм, сложность

Объясните пожалуйста как можно подробнее , что такое Р задачи , NP (полные , сложные ..) задачи . А то почитав так и не понял. 
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Подробнее Вам тут вряд ли расскажут, в Интернете полным-полно описаний, а ХэшКод - не для этого. А вот кратко, с чего начать - вполне

Comment: Хороший ответ по теме вопроса на братском подсайте: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/35138#35141

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Смотрите, речь идёт об асимптотической сложности задач. Здесь рассматриваются только задачи, которые имеют простой однозначный ответ: «да» или «нет». Например, «есть ли подстрока "XYZ" в данной строке?». Задачи типа «найдите все перестановки данного набора чисел» как **P**/**NP**-проблемы *не* рассматриваются, так как ответ тут не да/нет.

Алгоритмы часто параметризуются размерами входных данных. Время пробега алгоритма в общем случае тем больше, чем больше данных ему приходится обрабатывать. Обозначим n1, n2, ... — параметры, описывающие размеры входных данных, `t(n1, n2, ...)` — максимальное время работы алгоритма на данных такой длины.

Если известно, что `t(n1, n2, ...)` ограничено сверху многочленом от переменных `n1, n2, ...`, задача называется решаемой за полиномиальное время. Класс таких задач и обозначается как **P**, они считаются вычислительно несложными.

Теперь, что же такое **NP**-проблема?

Представьте себе, что у вас есть алгоритм с несколькими ветвлениями (`if`-ами, циклами), который последовательно тестирует решения, и как только найдёт подходящее, сразу заканчивает алгоритм с криками «ура, нашёл!» Например, если мы ищем, есть ли символ `'X'` в данной строке, мы можем поочерёдно в цикле проверять, совпадает ли первый символ с `X`, затем второй, затем третий, и как только нашли совпадение, заканчиваем работу. Так вот, представьте себе теперь такую машину, которая магическим образом сразу переходит к нужной итерации цикла: для поиска символа `X` в строке `"ABCXYZ"` она сразу проверяет в 4-ой позиции, то есть там, где надо! Такая магическая машина называется *недетерминированной* машиной (по историческим причинам) и, понятно, не существует в природе.

Так вот, проблема называется **NP**-проблемой, если она решается за полиномиальное время на этой самой читерской недетерминированной машине.

Понятно, что всякая **P**-проблема есть **NP**-проблема: если уж мы на нормальной машине решим её за полиномиальное время, то на читерской тем более! Возникает вопрос: а нужно ли читерство? Может быть, всякая проблема, которая решается на недетерминированной машине за полиномиальное время, может быть решена и на нормальной тоже за **полиномиальное** время?

Это и есть знаменитая **P**/**NP**-гипотеза: предполагают, что есть проблемы, которые без недетерминированной машины за полиномиальное время не решить. Но никто пока не смог это строго математически обосновать. Проблема тут вот в чём: если мы не умеем решать какую-то задачу за полиномиальное время, значит ли это, что она в принципе за полиномиальное время не решается, или мы просто недостаточно умны и изобретательны?

Comment: +1, годная метафора с "читерством" НДМТ.

Comment: @VladD, а что за задачи, которые не решаются за полиномиальное время? Имхо, любую вычислительную задачу можно вычислить за полиномиальное время, пусть хоть и полином получится с очень высокими коеффициентами.

Comment: @SoloMio: Например, на текущий момент неизвестен полиномиальный алгоритм, который выясняет, изоморфны ли два графа (то есть, можно ли перенумеровать вершины у одного, чтобы он стал одинаковым со вторым). Вот [большой список](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems).

Не исключено, что эти проблемы таки решаются за полиномиальное время, если да, то [**P == NP**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_P_%D0%B8_NP). (Это тогда потянет на результат десятилетия в computer science.)

Comment: @VladD, еще такой вопрос, почему нельзя проэмулировать принятие за один шаг сразу нескольких решений с помощью многопоточности?

Comment: @SoloMio: не получится. Потому что количество вариантов перебора при росте параметра задачи стремится к бесконечности, а у вас количество реально одновременно работающих потоков ограничено количеством ядер.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вот такую одновременную проверку всех путей и выбор из них правильного (т.е. решения) нам обещают сделать в [квантовом компьютере](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) .