# Зачем нужна недетерминированная машина в определении NP-полноты?

Tags: алгоритм, теория, сложность

Никогда не был силён в теоретической части и считал, что NP-задачи - это просто те, которые не решаются за полиномиальное время. Объясните, пожалуйста, что даёт введение недетерминированной машины в определении NP (вопрос [P-класс задач и NP-класс задач](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271063/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-p-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%B8-np-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87))?

И есть ли задачи, не решаемые за полином на недетерминированной машине?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите. Недетерминизм — это по существу ускорение брутфорса.

Например, пускай нам надо выяснить, простое ли число `n`. Очевидный метод — проверять все числа `k`, меньшие `n`, на то, делится ли `n` на `k`. (Конечно, есть и более хорошие методы.) То есть, у нас есть серия проверок:

- `n` делится на 1?
- `n` делится на 2?
- `n` делится на 3?
- ...

Весь алгоритм будет O(n).

На недетерминированной машине проверка *сразу* находит нужное `k`, поэтому тут определение простоты O(1)!

По существу, переход к недетерминированной машине означает, что мы от задачи «*найти* `k`, удовлетворяющее условию» переходим к задаче «проверить, удовлетворяет ли `k` условию», так как выбор достаётся нам бесплатно.

---

Проблемы, не решаемые за полином даже на недетерминированной машине, существуют. Например, [NEXPTIME-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME)-проблемы. В Википедии приведён пример: поиск гамильтонова цикла в графе, определённом специальным образом (который экономит место за счёт времени обработки).

Comment: Так а недетерминированная машина разве может за один шаг проверить, что ни на одно k число не делится (когда n - простое)? И выдать "я бы пошла по нужному k, но раз я не пошла - значит n - простое" тоже не может?

Comment: @Михаил М: насколько я понимаю, может. Более формальное (альтернативное) определение недетерминированной машины такое: пускай у нас есть цикл по всем `k`. Для нормальной машины время пробега цикла есть _сумма_ времён пробега по отдельным итерациям, для недетерминированной — _максимум_ из времён пробега. То есть в случае простого `n` получаем такое же время.

Comment: @Михаил М: то есть она как бы идёт по всем веткам одновременно. Здесь мы уже плавно подходим к квантовым вычислениям, которые нечто похожее [вроде бы] реализуют, но это уже вопрос к физикам.

Comment: Ок... А эта возможность, ходить сразу по всем веткам, грубо говоря, убирает факториал из сложности алгоритма? N^n, если быть точным, т.к. с каждым шагом мы можем сэкономить в n раз больше операций. Т.е. таким образом определяется, что NP-задача имеет сложность выше полинома, но ниже или равно факториала?

Comment: @Михаил М Факториала там нет, там есть [экспоненциальная зависимость от количества возможных переходов машины,](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/632/what-is-the-difference-between-non-determinism-and-randomness) которая является следствием того, что НДМТ совершает [branching на каждом шаге.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine) Собственно, можно доказать следующую теорему: если задача распознавания решается на НДМТ за полиномиальное время, то она решается за экспоненциальное время на ДМТ.

Comment: @Михаил М: ну, смотря от алгоритма. Если у нас на каждом шагу всё больше «возможностей выбора», то получается как раз так, как вы говорите.

В общем случае прямую зависимость между оценкой времени для детерминированного и недетерминированного случая, насколько я понимаю, не так легко установить, т. к. непонятно, какую часть общего времени пробега может улучшить недетерминированный мгновенный выбор.